# Cloth not rendering

Tags: rendering

I am working on a scene with a cloth modifier. When in preview mode, it shows the cloth the way I want it but when I render it, the texture is completely deformed and the cloth modifier does not appear to be applied in the render. I checked in the physics tab, but the little camera button is checked, same as in the outliner. How do I apply the cloth modifier correctly in the final render?

[image: Left is is preview render, right the final render]

Answer (score 1):

Solved. I had a cloth modifier, subdivision modifier and solidify modifier applied to the towel. The cloth should be the first in the list of modifiers, not the last. Speeds up calculation of cloth physics a lot as well.

Answer (score 1):

This happens mainly when you put the *Subdivision Modifier* in the
*Modifiers* tab as default or not the same as your viewport subdivisions.

If that's the reason just put the render subdivision amount same as your viewport subdivision amount.